# javascript how can I add additional properties to an array's coordinates inside of a loop, without erasing the existing properties of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

I have narrowed down a bug in my program to the following.

The following loop works so long as maxlayout equals 1 but if it equals two thus making the loop run twice then the original values erase.

so if the loop is run once then mainArray.tilef0 will equal tile.empty
but if tan twice then mainArray.tilef0 will be undefined and mainArray.tilef1 will equal tile.empty

The same is true for the rest of the properties such as terrain and solid.

```
for (var k = 0; k < maxlayout; k++){
       mainArray[i][j] = {
          ['tilef' + k]: tile.empty,
          ['terrainf' + k]: "empty",
          ['solidf' + k]: "false",
        };
```

**Barmar and Henery** Answered my question but I thought I would add the whole code below. So that they or others could see how it helped and/or help me or others to see if there is a better way such as maybe initializing the array before the point I needed help in.

So below is the functioning version with the code they assisted me with.

I apologize if it is messy, I struggle to keep code clean and don't know all the standard ways of doing things. But I added lots of comments.

```js
function gameloop() {                           // Entire Game contained withing function
  var mainArray = [];                           // most game data will be held withing the array
  var mapSizeX = 32;                            // sets the height of the rendered map and corresponding array coordinates
  var mapSizeY = 128;                           // sets the width
  var idPos = {x: 16, y: 64};                   // currently used to set player location and check for collisions
  var rendFlr = 0;                              // sets which floor to render
  var maxlayout = 3;
  
  
  var tile = {                                  // lists charcters used for rendered tiles and objects
    player: "☺",
    empty: ".",
    wall: "#",
    oak: "♠",
    maple: "♣",
    grass: "‚",
    tallgrass: "„"
    
  };

  function initMap(mapSizeX, mapSizeY) {        // expands and populates the array
    for (var i = 0; i < mapSizeX; i++) {
      mainArray.push([])                        // I belive this is only expaning it 2 dimesionaly and matching the height

      for (var j = 0; j < mapSizeY; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < maxlayout; k++){
                const obj = mainArray[i][j] || {};   // creates on object to alter and add back into the main array    
                obj['tilef' + k] = tile.empty;
                obj['terrainf' + k] = "empty";
                obj['solidf' + k] = "false";
                mainArray[i][j] = obj;
                
                if(k > 0){
                    if (j == 0 ||                           // wraps the underground floor 1 in walls
                        j == mapSizeY - 1 ||
                        i == 0 ||
                        i == mapSizeX - 1) {
                        mainArray[i][j]['tilef' + k] = tile.wall;
                        mainArray[i][j]['terrainf' + k] = "wall";
                        mainArray[i][j]['solidf' + k] = "Wall";
                        }
                }
                
            }
        
        //else{                                 // un need as the above for j is already creating empties
            //mainArray[i][j].terrain = "empty";
            //mainArray[i][j].solid = "false";
        //}
      }
    }
  }
  
  function getRndInteger(min, max) {                            // returns random number from min to max number appears to not function predictably if min and max are the same number
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
  }
  
  function randAdd(odds,feature,solid) {                        // A chance to add named feature and solid type or message if the "odds" or max number provided is rolled.
    for (var i = 0; i < mapSizeX; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < mapSizeY; j++) {
            if (mainArray[i][j].terrainf0 === "empty") {
             roll = getRndInteger(1,odds);
                if(roll === odds){
                    mainArray[i][j].terrainf0 = feature;
                    mainArray[i][j].tilef0 = tile[feature];
                    mainArray[i][j].solidf0 = solid;   
                }     
            }
        }
    }
  }
  
  function randAdd1(odds,feature,solid) {                      // Same as above function but for floor 1 and should eventually be merged into a single function
    for (var i = 0; i < mapSizeX; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < mapSizeY; j++) {
            if (mainArray[i][j].terrainf0 === "empty") {
             roll = getRndInteger(1,odds);
                if(roll === odds){
                    mainArray[i][j].terrainf1 = feature;
                    mainArray[i][j].tilef1 = tile[feature];
                    mainArray[i][j].solidf1 = solid;   
                }     
            }
        }
    }
  }

  function genMaps(){
    randAdd(200,"wall","solid rock");
    randAdd(100,"oak","a tree");
    randAdd(100,"maple","a tree");
    randAdd(2,"grass","False");
    randAdd(2,"tallgrass","False");
    randAdd1(1,"wall","solid rock");
  }

  function nl() {                                           // Creates a new line in the rendered text
    GameScreen.innerText += "\n";
  }

  function render(flr) {                                       // displays the array tiles to the browser
    GameScreen.innerText = mainArray.map(arr => arr.map(cell => cell['tilef' + flr]).join("")).join("\n");
    nl();
    nl();
  }


  function reposition(xChange, yChange, strA) {             // checks if target position is not blocked and if not moves the player 
    if (mainArray[idPos.x + xChange][idPos.y + yChange].solidf0 === "false" || 
        mainArray[idPos.x + xChange][idPos.y + yChange].solidf0 === "False" ||
        mainArray[idPos.x + xChange][idPos.y + yChange].solidf0 === "") {
      mainArray[idPos.x][idPos.y].tilef0 = tile[mainArray[idPos.x][idPos.y].terrainf0];
      idPos.x = idPos.x + xChange;
      idPos.y = idPos.y + yChange;
      mainArray[idPos.x][idPos.y].tilef0 = tile.player;
      GameLog.innerText = "You take a step to the " + strA 
    } 
    else {
      GameLog.innerText = "You can not enter " + mainArray[idPos.x + xChange][idPos.y + yChange].solidf0;
    }
    mainArray[idPos.x][idPos.y].terrainf0 != "empty" ?
        GameLog.innerText += "\n There is " + mainArray[idPos.x][idPos.y].terrainf0 + " in this spot" : 
        GameLog.innerText += "\n There is nothing in this spot";
    
    render(rendFlr);
  }

  //Startup
  initMap(32, 128);
  genMaps();
  mainArray[idPos.x][idPos.y].tilef0 = tile.player;
  //First Render
  render(rendFlr);

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 38) {
      reposition(-1, 0, "North");
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 40) {
      reposition(1, 0, "South");
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 37) {
      reposition(0, -1, "West");
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 39) {
      reposition(0, 1, "East");
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 190) {
        if(rendFlr < maxlayout) {rendFlr++}
      render(rendFlr);
    } if (event.keyCode === 188) {
        if(rendFlr > 0) {rendFlr--}
      render(rendFlr);
    }
    //alert(event.keyCode);
  });
}



gameloop();
```

```css
.info {
  color: #7d7d7d;
  font-family: Lucida Console;
}

.info span {
  color: #ABABAB;
  font-family: Lucida Console;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

#GameScreen{
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Lucida Console;
  font-weight: italic;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#GameLog {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Lucida Console;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dungeon Valley</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<p class="info">Dungeon Valley.<br>
  <span class="">
    Taming the Borderlands.<br> v0.008 By heromedel.
  </span>
</p>
<section id="GameScreen"></section>
<section id="GameLog">Arrow Keys to move.<br></section>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to test it I recommend running the snippet then clicking fullscreen
Arrow keys to move , and . will change which floor is rendering.

Comment: It really helps get better answers if your code sample is complete... i.e. if `mainArray[i][j]` were defined within your sample.  That way we can drop it into console or something to check our suggestions.  Just a gentle suggestion, hope it helps. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barmar's answer identifies the issue, but will very likely run into `undefined` error, if mainArray[i][j] is not initialized.  So something like this:

```
for (var k = 0; k < maxlayout; k++){
       const obj = mainArray[i][j] || {};       
       obj['tilef' + k] = tile.empty;
       obj['terrainf' + k] = "empty";
       obj['solidf' + k] = "false";
       mainArray[i][j] = obj;
}
```

Comment: It took a bit to understand your code but I realized you are creating a new obj and setting the properties and then adding their value into MainArray[i][j]

if I am understanding correctly some of this is to get around behavior oddities between object.property vs object[property]

Either way I plugged it into my code and it worked flawlessly thank you

Comment: It is not pretty syntax, but the important bit is `const obj = mainArray[i][j] || {};` which returns an empty object if `mainArray[i][j]` is not defined (technically if it is falsy), but returns the current value if it is already defined.  This is a common thing to have to do in JavaScript.  There may be a cleaner syntax in your specific situation if we knew more about how `mainArray` is defined and used, but you do have to find some way to make sure you handle the `undefined` scenario.

Comment: Thanks Again :) 

I updated the question to show the complete code in case anyone is interested.

Comment: Glad it helped, based on the code you added, I would suggest you rename `obj` to `tile` or something similar.  `obj` was just a generic placeholder since I did not know what the code did.  Basically I don't want my terrible variable name to make your code harder to read :-D

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the array element instead of adding new properties to it.

```
for (var k = 0; k < maxlayout; k++){
    mainArray[i][j]['tilef' + k] = tile.empty;
    mainArray[i][j]['terrainf' + k] = "empty";
    mainArray[i][j]['solidf' + k] = "false";
};
```

Comment: This is what I thought would work but for some reason, the array doesn't render when I do this. It appears I may have to show the entire code to get help as I am still unsure what is wrong.

Comment: This assumes that all the array elements are initialized to empty objects. @HenryMueller's answer does it right if the elements are not initialized.